# Powershell Read Users from ActiveDirectory , sort and group the result

Tags: powershell

I want to read users from different Active Directory groups and  then sort and group the results.
From a list like

```
UserName   UserGroup
UZZ        GAA
UKK        GAA
UZZ        GBB
ULL        GBB
```

I want to get that:

```
Username UserGroup
UKK      GAA
ULL      GBB
UZZ      GAA
```

So, from User UZZ I want to get only one entry in the list with the first value of UserGroup (first in the alphanumeric sort).
Till now I have the following code:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$Groups = (Get-AdGroup -filter * | Where {$_.name -like "G-Q-T*"} | select  name -expandproperty name)
$Table = @()
$Record = @{"GroupName" = """Username" = ""}

Foreach ($Group in $Groups) {
    $Arrayofmembers = Get-ADGroupMember -identity $Group | select name, samaccountname

    foreach ($Member in $Arrayofmembers) {
        $Record."GroupName" = $Group
        $Record."UserName" = $Member.samaccountname
        $objRecord = New-Object PSObject -property $Record
        $Table += $objRecord 
    }
}

$Table |  Sort-object -property  Username   | Group-object -property  Username  |  export-csv "U:\members.csv" -NoTypeInformation**
```

The part making the list works fine. But not the sort and group part.
Thank you a lot for an answer and help.

Meanwhile I found out, that I have also to add the SID into the .csv File.
The SID is also in the Get-AdGroupMember. But then I try to implement is as the following, the output in case of SID stays empty. What did I wrong where? Thank you in advance for an answer:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$Groups = (Get-AdGroup -filter "name -like 'G-Q-T*'" | select name -expandproperty name)
$Table = @()
$Record = @{
"GroupName" = ""
"Username" = ""
"SID" = ""
}

Foreach ($Group in $Groups)
{
$Arrayofmembers = Get-ADGroupMember -identity $Group | select name,samaccountname,SID

foreach ($Member in $Arrayofmembers)
{
$Record."GroupName" = $Group
$Record."UserName" = $Member.samaccountname
$Record."SID" = $Member.SID
$objRecord = New-Object PSObject -property $Record
$Table += $objRecord 
}
}


$Table | Group-Object -Property Username |
Select-Object @{n="UserName";e={$_.Name}} , @{n="GroupName";e={$_.Group | Sort-Object GroupName | Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty GroupName}} , @{n="SID";e={$_.SID | Sort-Object SID | Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty SID}}| Export-Csv "U:\member.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: You seem to be getting into a mess with an array of objects, each with a hashtable as a parameter.  Things will be easier if you create some `PsCustomObjects` and add these to `$table` instead.  Also, if you only want the first item in the group, you will need to use `Select-Object -First 1` to get it.

Answer (score 0):

I would group on username and use calculated properties to create the desired result. Sort the groupnames in the group and pick out the first value. Try to replace your last line with:

```
$Table | Group-Object -Property Username |
Select-Object @{n="UserName";e={$_.Name}}, @{n="GroupName";e={$_.Group | Sort-Object GroupName | Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty GroupName}} |
Export-Csv "U:\members.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Avoid `-Filter *` as it retrieves every group. Use it to get only the groups you need

```
$Groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter "name -like 'G-Q-T*'"
```

Alternative using the famous pipeline:

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter "name -like 'G-Q-T*'" | ForEach-Object {
    $groupname = $_.Name

    $_ | Get-ADGroupMember | ForEach-Object {
        New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{
            UserName = $_.SamAccountName
            SID = $_.SID
            GroupName = $groupname
        }
    }
} | Group-Object -Property UserName |
Select-Object @{n="UserName";e={$_.Name}}, @{n="SID";e={$_.Group[0].SID}}, @{n="GroupName";e={$_.Group | Sort-Object GroupName | Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty GroupName}} |
Export-Csv "U:\members.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Hello. Meanwhile I found out, that I have also to add the SID. This value is also in the

Comment: `Group-Object` creates new objects per group. To get the SID, you need to pick the first element in the groups `Group`-property and extract it's SID. See updated example